# Drawing a jumped curve on the Anthor curve

Tags: python, plot

I Just want to plot something like this:
[image]

I have calculated the gray curve and I know the function of blue diagram. I want to set each blue line to my curve with time shift for each 10 days. because my original data is very big if you want to validate you can use these data. you can use this adopted code.

```
def func(t,a,b,c,d):
    return a*np.log(t+b)+c+t*d
def func_R( t, a0, a1, a2, a3, a4):
    R1_fit_Curve=a0*np.exp(a1*(1-(28/t)**(4/5)))+a2*(t/((a3)**a4+t**a4))
    return R1_fit_Curve
t_t=np.arange(1,120000)/100
y=func(t_t,-204,0.65,-35,0.15)
y=y+0.2*np.random.normal(size=y.size)
plt.plot(y)
r=-func_R(t_t,-4.57625313e-02,1.00437115e-01,-1.65239879e-01,3.00962474e-04,8.27987589e-01)
plt.plot(r)
```

and the result:

[image]

Comment: what is your question exactly? if you have the curves calculated just plot them.

Comment: I would like to have more orange lines on the blue curve, every 10 days a plot just like upper one

Comment: then call `func_R` more times with different parameters and plot the result. You are only calling the function once, so you only get one curve to plot

Comment: Which parameter? the orange one should start from the blue curve is not as simple as you think. I want the same orange curve to start from the blue curve 10 days later.

Comment: the Rs in upper are all the same R with a time shift.

Comment: For a given curve start at t0 and discard all times where the orange curve is below the blue one. this way you will only plot from the time where the orange in on top. your time will have to be fine enough for the gap to not be seen.